# C# App running on IIS Server to have OKTA Authentication with windows Auth as true

Tags: c#, iis, windows-authentication, okta, bearer-token

Runs app in C# running on IIS Server but need to have OKTA Authentication with windows Auth as true and Anonymous Auth as false. I can get it working with Windows as false, how to I achieve OKTA ith Windows as True on IIS Server. My app has services and is running as Server and it need to be OKTA enabled.

I understand the windows Authentication and OKTA Bearer authentication are two totally different things, but I cannot set Windows Authentication as false on IIS Server as other team is handling who are unwilling to change it.

PLEASE NOTE: I dont need OpenIdConnect here , I need a Bearer token for services App Server running on IIS Server to run with OKTA authentication.  My App has to run on IIS Server, Has to have win Auth as true.

Issue is it expects the request as challenge as Negotiate or NTLM when windows Auth as true and Anonymous Auth as false.

Response Headers
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM

Response is IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 401.2 - Unauthorized

Comment: The 401.2 responses are just part of Windows authentication (challenge based). So, receiving them on browser side is nothing wrong. What else did you observe? That might be the real issue to investigate.